# How to solve Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject?

Tags: android, json

I am trying to send data to server and my application crash and show this error can any one help me with this........

```
 Error Parsing dataorg.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
12-10 10:54:46.630: W/dalvikvm(870): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409961f8)
 FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
 java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at info.androidhive.slidingmenu.RegistrationForm$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(RegistrationForm.java:435)
    at info.androidhive.slidingmenu.RegistrationForm$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(RegistrationForm.java:1)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
    ... 5 more
 Activity info.androidhive.slidingmenu.RegistrationForm has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@41888e70 that was originally added here
 android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity info.androidhive.slidingmenu.RegistrationForm has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@41888e70 that was originally added here
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:343)
    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:245)
    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:193)
    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:118)
    at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:537)
    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:274)
    at info.androidhive.slidingmenu.RegistrationForm$AttemptLogin.onPreExecute(RegistrationForm.java:375)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:561)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:511)
    at info.androidhive.slidingmenu.RegistrationForm.onClick(RegistrationForm.java:291)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3480)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:13983)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

check my code here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27393384/how-to-send-data-from-android-to-php-server-using-json?noredirect=1#comment43233981_27393384

Comment: Check your JSON File coming from your server. your script might have some errors.

Comment: no dear its working fine,you can check my code here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27393384/how-to-send-data-from-android-to-php-server-using-json?noredirect=1#comment43233981_27393384

Comment: see my code here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27393384/how-to-send-data-from-android-to-php-server-using-json?noredirect=1#comment43233981_27393384

Comment: I noticed that you have Log for your JSON file, but your logcat is not showing that JSON file. Either you did not show it or the JSON file itself is not properly being send to your app.

Comment: Can you show us your php code? if it's possible.

Comment: What is at RegistrationForm.java:435 ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27393384/how-to-send-data-from-android-to-php-server-using-json?noredirect=1#comment43233981_27393384

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part of the logcat :

> Error Parsing dataorg.json.JSONException: Value **`<br`** of type java.lang.String cannot

All most like you hit a break tag `<br />`. The issue is that you are not getting any `JSON` data.

You need to investigate why, possible reasons:

1. Network issue
2. Permission issue
3. Invalid response

---

```
class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    boolean failure = false;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        ....
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String...args) {
        .....
        try {
            //Building Parameters
            .....

            json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest (
            LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);
            Log.d("Request attempt", json.toString());
            JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(json.toString());
            return jobj;

        }catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject jobj) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        try {
            if(jobj.getString(TAG_SUCCESS)){
                final String msg = jobj.getString("msg");
                Toast.makeText(
                      getApplicationContext(),msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                     .show();
            }else{
                System.out.println("FAIL !!");
            }

        }catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: no network issue,and tell me which permission except internet i should add,what do you mean invalid response? this is my response i can see in browser {"status":"error","msg":"Profile name already exists. Please choose another"}

Comment: @Johnson `<br` is what your app failing to convert to JSON, network issue meaning the app and the server cannot talk to each other, could be simple as bad url. it is invalid response because it is not JSON you are attempting to read

Comment: can you check my code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27393384/how-to-send-data-from-android-to-php-server-using-json?noredirect=1#comment43233981_27393384

Comment: it shows error near return jobj and in postexecute it shows The operator && is undefined for the argument type(s) boolean, String

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66542/discussion-between-meda-and-johnson).

Comment: can you help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27570948/how-to-upload-multiple-images-to-server