# upload multiple images to server

Tags: android, json, image-uploading

I am creating one app and in my app I added one option to browse image from gallery and then upload to server,I asked this question before but did not get good answers,and for uploading image I am following this tutorial http://mayanklangalia.blogspot.in/2014/04/how-to-upload-multiple-images-on-php.html and below I post my code can any one help me with that

from my photsfragment class i am passing id like this and passing it to photoupload activity click on see below images

[image: first image click on photo]
[image: it ask for select picture]
[image: i select and click on go and it should display in grid]
[image: here it shows blank]

Comment: So what errors are you getting?

Comment: You post the complete code of two activities. Why? Do not just dump all the code you have and let us find out. Better post only the code that gives problems. And tell how it should work and then what does not work. You said you used a multiple images upload example. So why does this not work for you? You should have explained.

Comment: after click on select picture it allows me to select pictures but after selection it not transfer selected images to next activity

Comment: @Johnson greenapps is right you posted a lot of code, you should remove irrelvant part and explain in details what went wrong

Comment: the problem is see the image i upload,there is photo option it should intent to photoupload activity and its not intent to photoupload activity

Comment: even i'm looking for an answer to this question

Comment: i solved it but at a time single image can upload..