# storage/sdcard showing images but gallery shows nothing

Tags: android, android-gallery

I am using eclipse juno and in my ddms `storage/sdcard` shows images but `in gallery it shows no media found`,i need to add images in my gallery i do not know what is problem in my avd can any one tell me,how can i show images in gallery
[description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZS3x.png)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

place the images in DCIM folder and restart the eclipse and avd.

Comment: Failed to push the item(s). it shows like this

Comment: i hope this link helps you  http://stackoverflow.com/a/20834609/2633173

Comment: in DCIM i added but still gallery has nothig

Comment: you are trying with emulator or device?

Comment: emulator only and i am trying to run my project where i need to load images from gallery

Comment: please place code for getting the gallary images in your application?

Comment: how can i put whole project dear

Comment: no need entire project, just place a method where your are getting the images from gallary?

Comment: follow this question we are doing one project http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27570948/how-to-upload-multiple-images-to-server

Comment: i accept and vote up..you vote up question

Answer (score 0):

Hello friends please follow below step:

Eclipse->Window->Show View->DDMS->File Explorer->

Select the Push a file onto the device

In the emulator select the Dev Tools->Media Scanner.

And then your images will be added in the gallery .

Restart your emulator.

Comment: i did all steps but instead of mnt/sdcard images are showing in storage/sdcard..and in mnt/sdcard sdcard folder is not expanding